# Access 2013 - sequential numbering without autonumber

Tags: ms-access, database-design

New to this site and access.
I am trying to create a database to keep track of a master log. Need help with sequential numbering. I currently have the following tables.

**PO Table**
  *POID* - Autonumber(PK)
  *PODate* - Date/Time
  *Supplier* - String

**Item Table**
 *ItemID* - Autonumber(PK)
 *POID* - Ingeter(FK)
 *ItemDescription* - String
 *Quantity* - Integer

**MasterLog Table**
 *MasterLogID* - Autonumber(PK)
 *ItemID* - Integer(FK)
 *PieceNumber* - Integer ( 1,2,3 ... etc)
 *MFG* - String
 *Process* - String
 *Length* - Integer
 *MfgIDNum* - String (ABD123XTY-1234)

I am trying to automate the data entry of the PieceNumber field. So when you enter a new PO and add items to it, once received. It will add a row to the masterlog table starting at piece number 1 through how ever many pieces we have. We number the pieces based on the items we purchased.(i.e. with Item 1 we purchased 100 pieces. So I would have Item 1 piece 1 through 100.) Then we are able to add the other data to the table. Just trying to reduce some data entry time and avoid some mistakes in the numbering of this field.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this would be a very simple way of doing it.  You'd have to have a predefined table called Numbers with integers starting from 1 to however high a quantity you might have:

```
INSERT INTO MasterLog (ItemID, PieceNumber)
SELECT Item.ItemID, Numbers.Number
FROM Item, Numbers
WHERE (Item.ItemID = Forms!Items!ItemID) AND 
   (Numbers.Number <= Item.Quantity) 
ORDER BY Numbers.Number
```

If you wanted to add the pieces one by one you could default the PieceNumber field on the related form.  Make sure you default MasterLog.ItemID as well:

```
=Nz(DMax("[PieceNumber]","[MasterLog]","[ItemID] = " & Forms!Items!ItemID), 0) + 1
```

For a VBA solution try something like this:

```
Dim db As Database
Dim strSQL As String
Dim frm As Form
Dim i As Integer

    Set db = CodeDb()
    Set frm = Forms!Items

    If frm!Quantity > 0 Then
        For i = 1 To frm!Quantity
            strSQL = "INSERT INTO MasterLog (ItemID, PieceNumber) " & _
                "SELECT " & frm!Item & " AS ItemID, " & _
                i & " AS PieceNumber"
            db.Execute strSQL, dbFailOnError
        Next i
    End If

    Set db = Nothing
```

All of these presume a form displaying your current item called Items.

Comment: Ok. I will give that a try. I was thinking I could do a loop using VB,                      i = 0

Comment: @jdwk6 That's perfectly fine, too.  Was trying to give you non-code options.

Comment: Sorry not used to the comments section i was trying to enter more info into my comment and realized that i couldn't press enter. I'm not real sure about creating a another table as my quantities will vary so much. It could be a small quantity to a large quantity so I would have to create a table that has a very large amount of numbers for the off chance that we get an order that has that large of quantity. I will try this option though. Thanks.

Comment: @jdwk6 okay, if you absolutely need code and need help let me know and I'll include a VBA solution

Comment: This worked great. It will do for now but I would like to get a VBA solution as I would like to automate this task. Is there a way to select the current item and quantity without having to reenter info into the pop up boxes when i run the query?

Comment: @jdwk6 I added a VBA solultion.  My preference would be for the first solution--you could pop it into a query then run it using a macro.  Hope this helps.